# E 4.5 Aquaris Removing persistant scopes/apps

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

Just learning about the E 4.5 Aquaris and as part of a spring-cleaning exorcism I checked the storage in 'about this phone'.

**It seems there are a significant number of scopes/apps that reside somewhere which I thought I had already removed.**
(maybe in custom/click/com.canonical.scopes) Cut-the-rope alone is 30.7mb
So whilst they are inactive, they lurk. I suspect these are not removable. Can this be right?

I have used both terminal and USB-to-desktop as well as the removal facilities that are in Ubuntu store, with no success. I have to say the E 4.5 is my first smart phone and am really enjoying its abilities.

However can anyone shed some light on this issue as I can't believe these particular scope/apps are needed for a viable OS. I see other queries to this effect but no real answers.

Comment: Thank you for the acceptance! your question edited and upvoted to increase readability so that the next user with the same problem can find it easier...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Ubuntu Touch isn't very strong in garbage clean-up, so some files of some applications don't get deleted when the application is removed...

Only a reset to default factory settings does that, but then you lose all applications/settings that you had!

(which aren't provided here to prevent a less tech-savvy user then you from executing them, leading to disastrous results)

**Alternatively,** you can install a terminal and delete the files there or if you like a GUI, install the file manager and delete them there.  But if I want to delete all of the trials I've installed *easily*, I just reset to default factory settings every 6 months.

Comment: Thank you Mr Back-up, I guess it's early days for Ubuntu on phones. Sure it will get sorted along the road. I was a bit surprised sudo was ignored. Don't want to poke it too much as it's a very different animal to desktop.

Comment: Well there is developer mode which I have yet to try. Would that unlock a few doors?

Comment: I had the impression, that with a new update being available, some files of deleted programs get deleted, but I am not 100% sure ...

Comment: @Bruni: find out and post another answer..  ;-)